# Access a variable in a child flash file through a parent flash file using javascript

Tags: javascript, flash, variables

I have the need to change a variable in a child Flash file.

The setup is a parent Flash file, that has called a child Flash, and placed it in a `movieClip`.

I can send a variable using Javascript to the parent Flash file, but not directly to the child Flash file. Is there a way that I can access the child Flash file directly with Javascript?

Or do I need to send the variable to the parent Flash file, and then have the parent send the variable to the child Flash file?  Is there a sort of dot notation that I can use with Javascript to get to the child Flash file without first accessing the parent, when the child is added to the parent using the `loadClip` function in flash?

Answer (score 0):

yeah..

from flash 8 you can use ExternalInterface. it is bidirectional.

in your first SWF(fla) you call the javascript function with paramaters like:

in SWF -->

```
ExternalInterface.call("setValue", form, field, publish);
```

in javascript

```
function setValue(form, field, publish) {
    alert(form + " " + field + " " + publish)
}
```

for bidirectional to your parent SWF you can do something like this in your parent SWF:

```
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;
function getValueFromJavaScript(strTmp){  

 textMC.text = "Value received from JS" + str;

}

ExternalInterface.addCallback("sendValueToFlash", this, getValueFromJavaScript);
```

in Javascript:

```
 <script >  
   function getFlashMovie(movieName) {
       var isIE = navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft") != -1;
       return (isIE) ? window[movieName] : document[movieName];
   }  
   function formSend() {
       var text = "Hello Flash";
       getFlashMovie("ExternalInterfaceExample").sendValueToFlash(text);
   }
   </script>
```